# __call__ method as classmethod not working?

Tags: python, class, methods, call

I was wondering why the **call** method inside of my class was not functioning when i declared the function as a classmethod.
Here is an example:

```
class Foo:
    bar = 0
    @classmethod
    def __call__(cls):
        print(cls.bar)
```

When i use Foo() it does not print out bar. Why?

Comment: I'm struggling to see why you would do this rather than just making a function. If this worked the way you wanted it to, you could never create an instance of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@classmethod` doesn't change *when* method lookup will find a method. It only changes *what arguments* get bound when a method is found.

Putting `@classmethod` on your `__call__` means that if you call an instance of your `Foo` class:

```
foo = Foo()  # not here
foo()        # here
```

the first argument to `__call__` will be the class, not the instance.

Putting `@classmethod` on your `__call__` will *not* mean that the method gets used for calling `Foo` itself. When looking up magic methods to implement language features, Python will in almost all cases bypass the ordinary method lookup procedure and perform a direct search through the object's class's MRO. Among other reasons, this avoids using `Foo.__call__` for `Foo()` in the much more common case where `Foo.__call__` is an instance method and was never intended to be called to implement the `Foo()` operation itself.

For a call `Foo()`, the object is `Foo` itself and its class is `type`, so the `__call__` lookup finds `type.__call__`, bypassing anything defined directly on `Foo`.